# metric with curvature bounded in $L^2$

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde

My question is about the regularity of a metric whose curvature is bounded in $L^2$. Of course, this question doesn't really make sense since the regularity of the metric depends on the coordinates choice.

But, thanks to Deturck-Kazdan, we know that harmonic coordinates are the best choice, more precisely, if $g\in C^2$ and $Ric\in C^{k,\alpha}$ for $k>0$ in harmonic coordinates then $g\in C^{k+2,\alpha}$.

The proof use some "classical elliptic theory" and the fact that in harmonic coordinates we get roughly speaking $\Delta g=Ric$.

My question is two folds.

1)  Assuming the existence of harmonic coordinates, do we have an $L^p$-estimate, like $Ric \in L^p$ then $g\in W^{2,p}$ for $p>1$. It seems reasonable with respect to regularity theory but I didn't find any reference.

2) let assume 1) with $p=2$ and $n=4$(dimension of the manifold). Then $g\in W^{2,2}$ but this space doesn't not belongs to $C^0$, hence it seems difficult to give sense to any harmonic coordinates since the coefficients of the Laplace-Beltrami won't be regular enough to apply the regularity theory. Can we give some sense to this assuming only $Rm$ or $Ric$ in $L^2$.

My motivation comes from the regularity theory for critical point of quadratic functional with respect to the curvature in dimension $4$, like $$\int_M \vert Ric_g\vert^2\, dv_g$$, for instance Einstein metric are critical point of this functional and they are known to be analytic (theorem 5.26 of Besse) assuming that the manifold is $C^1$ and I guess the metric at least $C^0$ before bootstraping. Can we give a sense to all this theory working only in energy space?

Comment: I don't know of any results with only an $L^2$ bound on the Ricci curvature on a 4-manifold. There are, however, results, where you assume only an $L^2$ bound on the Riemann curvature and a stronger bound on the Ricci curvature. See, for example, the papers of Anderson and Cheeger. Their work extends earlier results obtained independently by Z. Gao and M. Anderson on Einstein manifolds.

Comment: If the Ricci curvature is locally in $L^p$, where $p$ is greater than half the dimension of the manifold and there exist harmonic coordinates where the metric is bounded between two positive constants, then it is known that the metric is locally in $W^{2,p}$. I think you might find this in papers of Guofang Wei and/or Peter Petersen. You can also look at my paper,  Convergence of Riemannian manifolds with integral bounds on curvature. II. Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup. (4) 25 (1992), no. 2, 179–199.